# What is the Clojure way to implement for-loop?

Tags: clojure

In this question, you are given a value V and a list of unique integers. Your job is to find the number of distinct subsets of size 4 that sum up to V. Each element in the list can be used only once. If none of such subset can be found, output 0 instead.

For example, if the integers are `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and the value is `30`, the output should be 5. The subsets are:

```
[3, 8, 9, 10]
[4, 7, 9, 10]
[5, 6, 9, 10]
[5, 7, 8, 10]
[6, 7, 8, 9].
```

It is not hard to solve this question, the most direct way is to nest for-loop four times. What's the Clojure way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would've done it:

```clj
(ns example.solve
  (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo]))

(defn solve
  [s n v]
  (filter (comp (partial = v)
                (partial reduce +))
          (combo/combinations s n)))
```

I'm using [`math.combinatorics`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics) in my example, because it's a simplest way to get all combinations of 4 elements from a list.

Here is an example of using `solve`:

```
=> (solve [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] 4 30)
((3 8 9 10) (4 7 9 10) (5 6 9 10) (5 7 8 10) (6 7 8 9))
```

Comment: Very nice, just to illustrate the answer: `(solve [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 4 30)
((3 8 9 10) (4 7 9 10) (5 6 9 10) (5 7 8 10) (6 7 8 9))`

Comment: @JamesSharp Thanx! Added your example to my answer.

Comment: The comp function is brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `clojure.map.combinatorics/combinations` to get all 4-element subsets and then `filter` out those that do not sum up to V.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, this problem admits a (doubly?) recursive solution which involves only summing and counting (without actually generating the subsets.)

If you look at the initial element 3, then part of the solution is the number of sums taken from 3 elements in the rest of the sequence where the sum is 27, which is a smaller form of the same problem and can thus be solved recursively. The bottom of the recursion is when you are looking for sums produced from 1 element, which boils down to a simple check to see if the desired sum is in the list.

The other part of the solution involves looking at the next element 4, looking for sums in the rest of the list beyond the 4 equal to 26, and so on... This part can also be treated recursively.

Putting this together as a recursive function looks like the following, which produces the desired answer 5 for the example sequence.

```
(defn solve [xs n len]
  (if (seq xs)
    (if (= len 1)
       (if (some #{n} xs) 1 0)
       (+ (solve (rest xs)
                 (- n (first xs))
                 (dec len))
          (solve (rest xs) 
                 n
                 len)))
    0))

(solve [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] 30 4)               
;=> 5
```

Comment: I refactored your function to return the actual solution: https://gist.github.com/lbeschastny/e1f16b4f888bbb532526

Comment: Nice! I like how your refactoring has the same shape but replaces + with concat and deals with building up lists where needed. Thanks—insightful!

Comment: This also allows some short-circuiting if we know that the numbers are all positive.

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes. Perhaps if all are negative as well. Also the `(seq xs)` test could be expanded to consider `len`. The `combinatorics` solution is the simplest to understand IMHO, while this one appears to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of directly answering the question, here is how you could do it using indexes and a for loop:

```
(defn solve-for [xs v]
  (for [ndx0 (range 0          (- (count xs) 3))
        ndx1 (range (inc ndx0) (- (count xs) 2))
        ndx2 (range (inc ndx1) (- (count xs) 1))
        ndx3 (range (inc ndx2) (count xs))
        :when (= v (+ (xs ndx0) (xs ndx1) (xs ndx2) (xs ndx3)))]
    (list (xs ndx0) (xs ndx1) (xs ndx2) (xs ndx3))))
```

FWIW, this turns out to be about 70% faster than the approach using `clojure.math.combinatorics` but twice as slow as the doubly-recursive solution.